# Pug template, add breaklines to multiline JSON

Tags: json, pug

I have a JSON with one key with multiline value.

I´m trying that pug render this in multiline with breaklines, but it shows it in a line.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXjZZR

```
<pre>
    -
      var example = [
        {
          "company": "Orange Software",
          "website": "example.com",
          "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
          "services": [
            "Customer experience",
            "Digital strategy",
            "Velocity development"
          ]
        }
      ];

  body

    for i in example
      h1 #{i.company}
      p #{i.services}

</pre>
```

Comment: You mean you want the services array items to show up on multiple lines, correct? If so, you will have to iterate on your services array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all items in the `services` array is appended into the `<p>` paragraph tag, thus it is displayed in a single line.

```
<h1>Orange Software</h1>
<p>Customer experience,Digital strategy,Velocity development</p>
```

To show it in different lines, you should iterate the `services` array as well, and add individual array items to separate `<p>` paragraph elements.

```
for i in example
  h1 #{i.company}
  for j in i.services
    p #{j}
```

Which renders to,

```
<h1>Orange Software</h1>
<p>Customer experience</p>
<p>Digital strategy</p>
<p>Velocity development</p>
```

Please let me know whether this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may chose the right answer and upvote it so that it would help other users. Thank you.